# Bootstrap toggle element and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, show

I have and element that should be displayed or hidden from different menu entries (e.g. its visibility toggled), and  a toggle button that should switch the visibility of the element, but there are menu locations the element should be visible regardless of the toggle button state.

```
<a class="menu-bar" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu">
    <span class="bars"></span>             
</a>
<div class="collapse menu surcarte" id="menu">
    <div class="dansmenu">
        some nice stuff comes here
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML above is OK. But if add this code in a top menu bar :

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu" onclick="somejavascript();return false;"> link 1 </a>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu" onclick="somejavascript();return false;"> link 2 </a>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu" onclick="somejavascript();return false;"> link 3 </a>
```

Each link will toggle the #menu element, first showing it, then hiding it and so and. But i want them to allways show the #menu element. Only the element with the "bars" class should act as a toggler.

I tryed to solve it with `$("#menu").show();` 
but the jquery command seams not working.
Then i tryed the following to find out what happened:

- click the link of class "menu-bar" to make the div appearing.
- use the command `$("#menu").hide();` => WORKS
- click the link of class "menu-bar" to make the div disapear : DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE
- click the link of class "menu-bar" to toggle the div once more : no effect
- use the `$("#menu").show();` => WORKS again
- click the link of class "menu-bar" to make the div disapear : WORKS
- use the `$("#menu").show();` => DOSN'T work anymore.

It seems that there is a double imbricated toggle command and i can't escape it.

How do i write a working `$("#menu").show();` ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but it sounds like you just need to use `toggle()`. Seeing your actual code would help a lot here

Comment: toggle can't be used because the #menu must be shown from several entries in a top menu bar. If the user clic on one item and show the #menu, and then, without action, if he clic on another top menu bar item, the toggle will then hide the #menu element... which is not what we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out my problem. 
I was trying this :

```
$("#menu").toggle()
```

where the right syntax was :

```
$("#menu").collapse('toggle')
```

Special thanks to Rory McCrossan who showed me the strating point.